# Plain file logging in winston

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I want to log just the data and not log level, timestamp etc. to a file.

```
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({                                                                                     
  transports: [                                                                                                     
    new (winston.transports.File)({                                                                                 
        filename: '/tmp/data.log',                                                                                  
        json : false,                                                                                               
        timestamp : function() {                                                                                    
            return '';                                                                                              
        }                                                                                                           
    })                                                                                                              
  ]                                                                                                                 
}); 

logger.log('info', "a")
```

It removes the timestamp from the line but log level still appears. Currently, file contains "info: a". I want it to log just "a". Is it possible to specify output format in winston?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, that formatting is sort of hardcoded into winston; you can see the logic for it in the `log` function of `common.js`, which is used by most of the default transports.

The way around this would be to write your own custom transport which doesn't rely on `common.log()`.

An aside: you can just provide a `timestamp: false` option to disable timestamp logging in the default transports.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the custom log format like this

```
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
transports: [
new (winston.transports.Console)({
timestamp: function() {
return Date.now();
},
formatter: function(options) {
// Return string will be passed to logger.
return options.timestamp() +' '+ options.level.toUpperCase() +' '+ (options.message ? options.message : '') + (options.meta && Object.keys(options.meta).length ? '\n\t'+ JSON.stringify(options.meta) : '' );
}
})
]
});
logger.info('Data to log.');
```